# "class template" versus "template class"

Tags: c++, templates, standards

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a template class and a class template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879535/what-is-the-difference-between-a-template-class-and-a-class-template)

I've seen several C++ gurus rip on people for calling something like

```
template <typename T>
class SomeClass
{
    //...
};
```

a template class instead of a class template. (Not a huge rip, mind you, but as an indication that someone isn't an experienced C++ programmer) Yes, the correct word is "class template" -- because it is a template used to generate classes.

But I don't understand why in typical conversation the distinction matters. Nobody listening to/reading what you've written is going to understand what you're talking about to mean anything else.

Is there some specific use of the words "template class" in the standard or otherwise which makes use of those words in that order grossly wrong?

Comment: Don't forget than there're lots of people who insist on "calling things right".

Comment: @sharptooth: I'm all for nitpicking minor technical or pedantic parts of answers (I am a C++ programmer at heart after all). But usually this comment is directed at the person making the comment rather than at the content of the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a template class and a class template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879535/what-is-the-difference-between-a-template-class-and-a-class-template) or [Class templates and template class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983146/class-templates-and-template-class)

Comment: @Charles: Fair enough. Voted to close my own question lol.

Comment: Both linked questions include other interpretations that some people attach to "template class".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclass_templates.htm) :

> Note the distinction between the terms
>   class template and template class:
>
> - Class template
>     is a template used to generate template classes. You cannot declare
>     an object of a class template.
> - Template class
>     is an instance of a class template.

This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y5ca42y.aspx) page seems to agree on this definition :

> Unlike function templates, **when
>   instantiating a class template**, you
>   must explicitly instantiate the class
>   by giving the arguments for the class
>   templates.
>
> [...]
>
> The compiler generates code for a
>   **template class** or function when the class or function is instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search yielded:

> Q:
>           Is there a difference between a function template and a
>           template function, or between a class template and a
>           template class?
>
> A:
>               The term "function template" refers to a kind of template.
>               The term "template function" is sometimes used to mean the
>               same thing, and sometimes to mean a function instantiated
>               from a function template.  This ambiguity is best avoided
>               by using "function template" for the former and something
>               like "function template instance" or "instance of a
>               function template" for the latter.  Note that a function
>               template is not a function.  The same distinction
>               applies to "class template" versus "template class".

Makes sense to me.

Comment: Link? :) I don't know RANDOM-INTERNET-SITE-HERE from RANDOM-INTERNET-SITE-HERE! :P

Comment: http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't make the correction, but I can see the logic behind it.  It's no different than calling a superclass a subclass or vice-versa.  What they're saying is inherently incorrect, and does not mean the same thing.

It's important, especially with more junior programmers, to think in terms of code, and that is not possible when you are translating the language back into english incorrectly.

Comment: Hmm.. thing is I strongly disagree with the analogy that it's like sub/superclass. If you mix up those two, confusion is almost inevitable. If you mix up "class template" and "template class", confusion almost never occurs.

Comment: @Billy: maybe the analogy is too strong a case, but the idea still holds... forgetting the difference between when to use the word sub and when to use super is a common error among junior programmers, probably just due to their visual similarity.  I'm not saying I'm worried about it causing confusion, rather I think it's doing someone a favor and helping their skills if the difference is clarified.